Logarithm map for groups defined over adelic ring
I've been reading the book Eisenstein series and automorphic representations and I am struggling to understand the definition of a logarithm map $H:G(\mathbb{A})\rightarrow \mathfrak{h}(\mathbb{R})$ (p.89 eq.5.100 of the book).
Let me recall some definitions. Throughout, our global field is $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $G$ be a reductive group whose Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $A$ be its maximal torus and denote the Cartan algebra as $\mathfrak{h}$. The authors define the logarithm map $H:G(\mathbb{A})\rightarrow \mathfrak{h}(\mathbb{R})$ by the formula $H(g)=H(nak)=H(a)=log|a|$, where we use Iwasawa decomposition to express $g=nak$ where $n\in N(\mathbb{A})$, $a\in A(\mathbb{A})$ and $k\in K_{\mathbb{A}}$. To define $log|a|$, they express $a\in A(\mathbb{A})$ as
$$a=exp\left( \sum_{\alpha\in\Pi}u_{\alpha}H_{\alpha}\right),\quad u_{\alpha}\in\mathbb{A},$$
where $\Pi$ is the set of simple roots of $\mathfrak{g}(\mathbb{R})$ and $H_{\alpha}\in \mathfrak{h}(\mathbb{R})$ is the corresponding Cartan generator. Then they define $log|a|=\sum_{\alpha}|u_{\alpha}|H_{\alpha}$.
My question is: how is the existence of such $u_{\alpha}$'s guaranteed? To claim such existence we might need an exponential map $exp:\mathbb{A}\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{\times}$ and it should be surjective for things to work. However, I am not even sure how the exponential map for $\mathbb{A}$ should be defined. I think there must be some convergence issue if we consider the exponential map for elements outside the ring of integers.
